# Date: getDate() wrong value from ISO 8601 date instance

Tags: javascript, date

I have a database that serves to client through AJAX a date, which is in format `ISO 8601`, parsing an `ISO 8614` format for date instance should be easy, but for some reason `date.getDate()` returns one day earlier of the provided day, i have no idea why it happens so for now i just make the function that calls the date method to raise the value by 1.

the code is simple:

```
function getFullDate(ISO){
    // ISO = 
    var date = new Date(ISO);

    return [
        date.getFullYear(),
        date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth(),
        date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + (date.getDate() + 1) : (date.getDate() + 1) //Get date returns 1 day early so raise by 1
    ].join("-");
}

console.log(getFullDate("2016-07-19T00:00:00.000Z")); // 2016-07-19
```

There's nothing wrong with the code, i just want to know why this happens, for now i only see it only happens with `ISO 8601` format

Comment: Your ISO date is interpreted as UTC time, but you're using the local time APIs to get the day-of-month etc. The UTC time is midnight of that day, so if you're west of Europe when you run that code you'll see the previous day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a date in UTC time but are using methods that will display in whatever timezone your machine is set to.

Check out the Date [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype) and use the methods that start with `getUTC...` such as [getUTCFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear)

Comment: so this happens because time is set to be `00:00:00` which is midnight, i didn't know all the date methods but i will keep this in mind

Comment: @nosthertus - not just midnight. Any time between midnight and X hours prior - X being your timezone difference (i.e. -0700 - so 20:00:00 would show as 3am the next day)